# Firebase Function Deployment Error - "User code failed to load"

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, eslint

I am encountering a persistent issue when trying to deploy a specific Firebase Cloud Function (`generateUploadUrl`). Despite trying multiple troubleshooting steps, I keep running into the error: "User code failed to load. Cannot determine backend specification" during deployment.

#### Error Description

Whenever I attempt to deploy the function using `firebase deploy --only functions:generateUploadUrl`, the process fails after the build step with the mentioned error. This issue occurs both with the `--debug` flag and without it.

#### Steps I've Tried

- Ensured Node.js version consistency (using Node.js v18 as specified in `package.json` and Firebase configuration).
- Reviewed and corrected `firebase.json` for any potential misconfigurations.
- Inspected the compiled JavaScript output in the `lib` directory to ensure it accurately reflects the TypeScript source code.
- Tested simpler functions locally using Firebase Emulators, which worked as expected.
- Updated Firebase CLI and SDKs to the latest versions.
- Checked for environment-specific issues and ensured that my local development environment matches the expected production environment.
- Ran lint and build processes, both of which completed successfully.

#### Project Setup

- Node.js version: 18
- Firebase CLI version: [Your Firebase CLI version]
- Main dependencies in `package.json`:

  ```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^7.7.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1"
  }
  ```
- Firebase function code:

> ```
> export const generateUploadUrl = onCall({maxInstances: 1}, async (request) => {
>   // Check if the user is authentication
>   if (!request.auth) {
>     throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
>       "failed-precondition",
>       "The function must be called while authenticated."
>     );
>   }
>
>   const auth = request.auth;
>   const data = request.data;
>   const bucket = storage.bucket(rawVideoBucketName);
>
>   // Generate a unique filename for upload
>   const fileName = `${auth.uid}-${Date.now()}.${data.fileExtension}`;
>
>   // Get a v4 signed URL for uploading file
>   const [url] = await bucket.file(fileName).getSignedUrl({
>     version: "v4",
>     action: "write",
>     expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
>   });
>
>   return {url, fileName};
> });
> ```

I have checked the function code for syntax errors and other common issues but haven't found anything that seems to be causing the problem.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this error and how to resolve it. Thank you in advance for your help!